# How to pack a program for easy Ubuntu installations?

Tags: 12.04, packaging

//Ubuntu newbie here

We have a framework that we need to be able to easy deploy on Ubuntu machines (12.04). Which format should I use? (RPM, deb, something else?)

How does one goes on to pack a program into a deb format? are there any tools for that?